# Calling functions only after drawing is completed

Tags: macos, swift

I am making a drawing on `NSView` using a timer that is set to update every .02 seconds. On update some physical simulation makes a step, and then `Canvas!.needsDisplay = true`. It works when app is in foreground (usually), but when some lags happen, simulation progresses forward despite the fact that view hasn't reflected it yet. How do I pause the timer during these times to make simulation happen only when `NSView` can show it? I do not want to call `step_over` from inside `drawRect`, cause it seems like a bad idea, because then it would be harder to stop the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this kind of update should be done the other way around, by letting the display ask you for frames as it can display them. This is done with a <strike>`CADisplayLink`</strike> `CVDisplayLink` (this is Mac; `CADisplayLink` is iOS). Configure it with a method you want to be called when a frame can be drawn.

Generally you *do* want your simulation to keep moving forward, even if it means dropping frames occasionally. For that, you check the timestamp and use that to work out what time to use for your new frame. But if you only want to move forward when the display can show it, then just update once per call.

Note that generating at 50fps is often going to mismatch the system that's trying to draw at 60fps, so you're going to wind up missing frames occasionally. That's one of several reasons not to try to push drawing with a timer.

See also [Alternative of CADisplayLink for Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158743/alternative-of-cadisplaylink-for-mac-os-x). Note that trying to draw at 50fps with Core Graphics usually isn't going to give good results in any case. The right tool here in OS X is Core Animation (or SpriteKit for games on 10.10, or OpenGL for more advanced high-speed rendering). You can do very basic animations with an `NSTimer` (and we did for years before Core Animation came along), but it's not really a tool for complex drawing.

Comment: My simulation and my display are pushed by timer. So, m simulation can stay pushed, and `CADisplayLink` should take care of drawing?

Comment: It's the other way around. `CADisplayLink` tells you when the screen can draw. Your display is not pushed by the timer. The display draws when the display draws (and that's not going to match exactly 50fps). You're just flagging the "I would like to draw next time you feel like drawing" at 50fps. Your use case seems odd. Why do you want to delay the model simulation just because a frame needs to be dropped? That's going to stutter visually.  There's no promise that your timer even fires at exactly 50fps (NSTimer just promises no *faster* than you request).

Comment: (BTW, why are you trying to hand-animate? iOS has several excellent animation libraries optimized to most common problems.)

Comment: This program is for OS X, and it is my first experience. I do not want to include any libraries yet, I just want to learn swift, and how GUI programming works.

Comment: And, apparently, OS X doesn't have a `CADisplayLink`

Comment: By the way, doesn't `needDisplay` only marks it for "update it whenever you have the time"?

Comment: I wouldn't say "whenever you have the time." It's "on the next draw event." But yes, that's the right idea. There's no precise promise on when the next draw event will be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79429/discussion-between-romavalcer-and-rob-napier).